# Switch directives in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an object in controller (e.g. `directives = [{type: 'toggle'}, {type: 'phone'}]`).

JavaScript code:

```
app.directive('toggle', function(){});
app.directive('phone', function(){});
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat='directive in directives'>
    <{{directive.type}}"></{{directive.type}}>
</div>
```

How can I switch directives in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, create 3d directive and compile appended directive based on condition

Comment: The other way is to use one directive that receives different parameters and changes its behavior regards to input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular directive **ngIf**, to show the appropriate directive. So your code would look like:

```
<div ng-repeat='directive in directives'>
    <toggle ng-if='directive.type == "toggle"'></toggle>
    <phone ng-if='directive.type == "phone"'></phone>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try that:
JS:

```
    var app = angular.module('test', [])


.controller('mainController', function($scope){
  $scope.directivesArray = [{type: 'toggle'}, {type: 'phone'}];
})


.directive('toggle', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.append($compile("<a>I'm the toggle directive</a>")(scope));
      }
    }
})

.directive('phone', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.append($compile("<a>I'm the phone directive</a>")(scope));
      }
    }
})

.directive('test', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace:true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('dirname',function(n){
          element.append($compile("<div " + n  + "></div>")(scope));
        })
      }
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='directive in directivesArray'>
      <test dirname="{{directive.type}}"></test>
  </div>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/afLxzZMrw7wQTPBfMtfo?p=preview)

Comment: The 'test' directive here demonstrates the right, 'angular' way to do what the questions asks; the original question is missing the $compile call, which can't be put in the raw HTML.  However, if you came to this question from Google, also look at the answer using `ngIf`, which is less robust but simpler for most situations.